# How can I create and run both an angular and react app in asp.net core 2.1 app?

Tags: asp.net-core

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) talks about creating an **angular** app in the `ClientApp` folder. I want to create a **react** app which can be accessed through another asp.net MVC route.

What changes I have to make in the asp.net core application created by the **Visual Studio 2017** to have both the SPAs running.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has most of the templates available at the release time of 2.1. I'm not sure if VS 2017 didn't include it for a reason, or if they are catching up to the ASP.NET Core team, but you can scaffold a new react app by simply opening a command line and typing

`dotnet new react`

The `dotnet new` templates are the same exact templates that VS 2017 creates for you, except for some reason the React one is missing from the UI at the moment.

Personally, I would not not tie my Angular or React project to the UI except in the case of a relatively simple app.  However, if you have two separate UI components for the same API, I would consider that a complex scenario and start to separate my concerns.

I would build 3 separate projects.

- Api/
- AngularApp/
- ReactApp/

There are many reasons to do this.

1. Angular has different dependencies than React, if try to force them in the same project you will probably get some dependency version conflicts.
2. Separation of concerns. Never a bad thing.
3. Angular has it's own CLI to scaffold the app, modules and components. I would use it to it's full capability, because that's what it was designed for.
4. Easier to develop. Each has a development server with file watchers to rebuild your project after you make changes to your file and hit save. .NET Core has `dotnet watch`, Angular has `ng serve`, node webpack and some others for react.
5. Deployment would be a breeze if you Dockerized your project. One `docker-compose` file could launch all 3 of the development servers.

Comment: Do you recommend for a production build?

Comment: Absolutely would recommend for production as well.

Comment: Do you mean running three servers (1) ```dotnet``` (2) ```ng serve``` and (3) ```node webpack``` in production as well?

Comment: @wonderfulworld no, you would run 1 server (iis or nginx) which would host all 3 apps in production

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've made the correction. It *was* AngularJS last time I actually created an angular project. .Net Core 1.0 preview. I wasn't happy with how the project was scaffolded so I haven't checked since (naughty me!).  That's where I got that idea from. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: .NET Core preview?! That was a very long time ago indeed, in the VS2015 era. The current template generates an Angular Universal project with server-side rendering and the Preview tooling removed server-side support in favor of loading Angular separately

Comment: Yes, I have since created a new angular app with the current template to validate that I was incorrect. I am now download VS 15.8 preview which supposedly scaffolds angular and .net core app separately. This might be more inline with my process and worth adding to the answer.